# jQuery: closest blank textarea

Tags: jquery, parent-child

I've got a dynamically-generated number of text areas on a form. What I'd like to do is find the nearest (nearest `$(this)` should work for my function, provided siblings lower down are considered further away) **blank** one, into which some content will be placed.

At the moment it specifies a particular one, thus:

```
var $poorarea = $('textarea#doc_edits_attributes_0_body');
```

But for the function to work it needs to be something like (very pseudocode):

```
var $poorarea = $(this).closest('textarea.editable_areas').empty();
```

Any help would be great. Parent/child stuff in jQuery confuses me at the best of times. It's vital that it find the nearest **blank** one, too.

The simplified HTML is here:

```
<div class="controls">
  <div id="preview_article" class="thumbnail">
    <ul class="thumbnails" id="sort_articles">
      <li class="span5">
        <input class="article_chooser" id="doc_article_ids_" name="doc[article_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="23" /> 
      </li>
      <li class="span5"> 
        <input class="article_chooser" id="doc_article_ids_" name="doc[article_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="24" /> 
      </li>
      <li class="span5">
        <input class="article_chooser" id="doc_article_ids_" name="doc[article_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="26" /> 
      </li>
      <li class="span5">
        <input class="article_chooser" id="doc_article_ids_" name="doc[article_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="27" /> 
      </li>
      <li class="span5">
        <input class="article_chooser" id="doc_article_ids_" name="doc[article_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="28" /> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">  
    <div class="tab-content">
      <textarea class="editable_areas" id="doc_edits_attributes_0_body" name="doc[edits_attributes][0][body]"></textarea>
      <textarea class="editable_areas" id="doc_edits_attributes_1_body" name="doc[edits_attributes][1][body]"></textarea>
      <textarea class="editable_areas" id="doc_edits_attributes_2_body" name="doc[edits_attributes][2][body]"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `textarea:empty` should work as your selector.

Comment: Nope, always targets the first one regardless of whether it's empty or not.

Comment: What is `this`? `closest()` selects the closest parent, and I'm guessing the textarea is'nt the parent of `this` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [pseudo-selector eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) in your jQuery code, which selects the given index from the array of elements, and run it through a for loop.

```
for(i = 0; i < $(".tab-content").children("textarea").length; i++){
    if($(".tab-content").children("textarea:eq(" + i + ")").val() == ''){
        //do whatever you need to do
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Same issue, that just targets the first textarea regardless of its content.

Comment: I updated the code with the correct objective. I wasn't aware that it was looking for the first *empty* `textarea`